# How to get latest inputs by pressing the up arrow (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, memory, input

How can i get the latest inputs I entered in order. For example:
I declared an array with 20 elements and when I input something I delete the first element of the array and add at the end the input I just entered.

So when I press the upArrow button the last element of the array will appear as the new input. If I press one more time the upArrow I want my input to change to my second last element and so on.

It doesn't work in my jsfiddle link. It outputs another element from the array.

```js
var singleValues;
var theInputsNumber = 19;
var latestInputs = new Array(20);
latestInputs.fill("Latest");

function clickMe(){ 
  singleValues = $( "#input" ).val();
  var c = latestInputs.shift();
  latestInputs.push(singleValues);
  $( "#output" ).append( singleValues);
  $("#input").prop('value', ''); 
}
$(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
    $('#input').bind('keydown', function(e) {
             if (e.which === 38) {
                $("#input").prop('value', latestInputs[theInputsNumber]);
                theInputsNumber--;
             }
        });
        if(e.which == 13) {
            theInputsNumber=19;
            clickMe();
            }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Think Fast Trivia</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

        
        <div  id="output" class="item1"></div>
        <input autofocus type="text" name="input" id="input" />
        <button id="send" onclick="clickMe()">Send</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the idea that you must determine (logic test) the value of the counter (`theInputsNumber`) in order to reset at the top (and the bottom) of the stack.

I renamed `theInputsNumber` counter and provided the UP key and DOWN key feature. I also did not limit the array size to 20 as that won't make a difference anyway (array size is not restricted in size as it is in other languages).

EDIT (based on comment): I've placed everything within the HTML so you can save this content into an HTML file and open with your browser. It will work just fine with no server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Think Fast Trivia</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="output" class="item1"></div>
  <input autofocus type="text" name="input" id="input" />
  <button id="send" onclick="clickMe()">Send</button>
  
  <script>
  var counter = 0;
var latestInputs = [];

function clickMe() {
  let input = $("#input").val();
  latestInputs.push(input);
  $("#input").prop('value', '');
}
$('#input').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 38) {
    $("#input").prop('value', previous());
  } else if (e.which == 40) {
    $("#input").prop('value', next());
  } else if (e.which == 13) {
    clickMe();
  }
});

function previous() {
  counter = (counter === 0) ? latestInputs.length - 1 : --counter;
  return latestInputs[counter];
}

function next() {
  counter = (counter === latestInputs.length - 1) ? 0 : ++counter ;
  return latestInputs[counter];
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think I've got to put the page on a server, that's why for example in some cases I press the up arrow and nothing happens if I open in a browser with those files associated. On jsfiddle works fine. Or I just have to download directly the JQuery ?

Comment: If you place the content here inside an HTML page with the script within script tags, it will work without a server.

Comment: @ztonaz - I edited my answer with all content in the HTML. Simply save that into an HTML file and open with your browser. it will work fine without a server.

Comment: Thank you for your comment...and for your time.
Your solution is pro like.
The only thing, if you link the script from an external js file, you've got to put it at the end of the body. If you put it in the head, up arrow it doesn't work. I just saw this

Comment: That was not part of the question, and is assumed. Just add the `defer` attribute to your script tag in the head and everything is fine. It is now considered best practice to add `defer` to your script tags. - If you think my answer is better, or you actually are using my solution, you can always change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your function on upArrow was triggered multiple times (3) every time you pressed that key, I moved it outside of the "keypress" binding and it stays on its own, and the problem no longer exists when i run the code

```js
var singleValues;
var theInputsNumber = 19;
var latestInputs = new Array(20).fill("Latest");

function clickMe() {
  singleValues = $("#input").val();
  latestInputs.shift();
  latestInputs.push(singleValues);
  theInputsNumber = 19;
  $("#output").append(singleValues);
  $("#input").prop("value", "");
}
  

     
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    clickMe();
  }
});
$("#input").bind("keydown", function (e) {
  var x = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (x === 38) {
    $("#input").prop("value", latestInputs[theInputsNumber--]);
    if (theInputsNumber === -1) {
      theInputsNumber = 19;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Think Fast Trivia</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

        
        <div  id="output" class="item1"></div>
        <input autofocus type="text" name="input" id="input" />
        <button id="send" onclick="clickMe()">Send</button>

</body>
</html>
```